# How to associate ec2 instance profile with ec2 instance in saltstack

Tags: salt-stack, salt-cloud

We want to setup association between the existing ec2 instance profile with ec2 instance using saltstack.

Comment: Any update on this question, for now I have implemented it by calling aws cli s3.

Comment: Anyway we can implement it in salt for the existing EC2.